# List out all artifacts in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, 2007, migration

I am going to migrate SP 2007 to SP 2013 skipping SP 2010, before that I want to get the list of artifacts exists in the SP 2007 (eg: List, Lib, workflows, event receivers, etc)

One important thing I want to get all custom component such as custom workflow, custom WebPart and so on.

In some case some list have LookUp column on that situation I want get that LookUp details too.

**Note:** I am trying to get those details via CMD Shell or Console App.

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no direct way to migrate 2007 to 2013. Its a two step process where you need to migrate to 2010 and then 2013.

For more on the migration topic you can check this - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141%28v=office.15%29.aspx

To get the artifacts a console application will be much more easier because of the Rich SeverSide API. Here is the pseudo code you can use

```
ForEach W in WebApplication
    ForEach S in W.Sites
        ForEach Web in S.AllWebs
            ForEach L in Web.Lists
            //Get the details
```

To find custom solutions, you can look the central admin -> system settings -> solutions page

Without code - You can use SharePoint Manager (https://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762) and use that to find the details.

Comment: Okay good, can i use any 3rd party tool to skip SP 2010. Is there is any option?

Comment: That is the recommended path. Even if you use 3rd party they will be also doing the same.